# Generar consultas dento de un form

Tags: php, symfony3, orm

Como puedo obtener una consulta desde el entity o generada al momento dentro de un campo de formulario.

tengo dos entidades EquipoPv y CatEquipoPv donde CatEquipoPv tiene una relación de OneToMany con EquipoPv

e intentando generar la consulta del siguiente modo para obtener los campos de dicha consulta dentro del campo test al momento de renderizar.

```
//EquipoPvType.php

....codigo....

->add('test', EntityType::class, array(
    "class" => "PvsBundle:EquipoPv",
    "choice_label" => 'catalogo',
    "query_builder"=>function (\PvsBundle\Entity\CatEquipoPv $er){
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('dt');
     }
 ));
```

pero obtengo este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución a esta problemática la cual resulto ser bastante simple. Y compartiré la respuesta como posible ayuda o guia a personas que se encuentren en una situación similar.

```
paso 1: usar la clase EntityRepository
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

paso 2: en el choice_label usar una instancia de la clase en cuestion
   en mi caso: "choice_label" => 'nombre',

paso 3: en el query_builder llamar a la función de la clase que incluimos previamente
"query_builder" => function (EntityRepository $er) {
   return $er->createQueryBuilder('dt')
 }
```

y ahora al momento de renderizar el form ya tengo una lista con columnas generadas por una consulta a la base de datos.